# HikariCP Connection aquistion errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp

I developed a simple spring boot application that has a jms listener on IBM MQ. It receives some messages, does some transformation, saves the result to DB and drops the result into a different queue on same queue manager. The app is containerized and deployed on Openshift.

The app starts up successfully and works fine too. But after a arbitary amount of time I see connection aquisition errors. During this time the app is idle and not handling any traffic.

Spring boot version : 2.2.9.RELEASE
odbc version : 12.1.0.2

Below are my log entries. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
2020-11-30 15:18:48.949  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.18.Final
2020-11-30 15:18:50.006  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-11-30 15:18:52.118 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - configuration:
2020-11-30 15:18:52.120 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : allowPoolSuspension.............false
2020-11-30 15:18:52.120 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : autoCommit......................true
2020-11-30 15:18:52.120 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : catalog.........................none
2020-11-30 15:18:52.120 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionInitSql...............none
2020-11-30 15:18:52.120 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTestQuery.............none
2020-11-30 15:18:52.121 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTimeout...............30000
2020-11-30 15:18:52.121 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSource......................none
2020-11-30 15:18:52.121 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceClassName.............none
2020-11-30 15:18:52.121 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceJNDI..................none
2020-11-30 15:18:52.121 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
2020-11-30 15:18:52.121 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : driverClassName................."oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
2020-11-30 15:18:52.121 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : exceptionOverrideClassName......none
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckProperties...........{}
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckRegistry.............none
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : idleTimeout.....................30000
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : initializationFailTimeout.......1
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : isolateInternalQueries..........false
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:oracle:thin:
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : leakDetectionThreshold..........0
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maxLifetime.....................2000000
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maximumPoolSize.................5
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricRegistry..................none
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricsTrackerFactory...........none
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : minimumIdle.....................2
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : password........................<masked>
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : readOnly........................false
2020-11-30 15:18:52.122 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : registerMbeans..................false
2020-11-30 15:18:52.123 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : scheduledExecutor...............none
2020-11-30 15:18:52.123 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : schema..........................none
2020-11-30 15:18:52.123 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : threadFactory...................internal
2020-11-30 15:18:52.123 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : transactionIsolation............default
2020-11-30 15:18:52.123 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : username........................"dummy"
2020-11-30 15:18:52.123 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : validationTimeout...............5000
2020-11-30 15:18:52.123  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-11-30 15:19:23.417  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
```

```
2020-11-30 19:42:51.988  WARN 1 --- [oundedElastic-4] o.s.b.a.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator   : DataSource health check failed

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: HikariPool-1 - Interrupted during connection acquisition
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:107) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:102) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.call(MonoCallable.java:91) ~[reactor-core-3.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:225) ~[reactor-core-3.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: HikariPool-1 - Interrupted during connection acquisition
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:944) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.ConcurrentBag.borrow(ConcurrentBag.java:151) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:180) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

2020-11-30 19:42:59.266  WARN 1 --- [oundedElastic-1] o.s.b.a.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator   : DataSource health check failed
```

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/703), which looks very familiar to your problem to me, maybe you also have a mismatch in timeouts between your application and your DB.